# Create an object that contains another object

Tags: c++

I am studying c++, and I am a bit confused about the following situation:

For example,

#### class Apple

```
  class Apple
  {
    int kg;
    Apple();
  }
```

#### class Fruit

```
  class Fruit
  {
    private:
      int count;
      Apple one;
    
    public:
      Fruit();//do we need to call the constructor for apple,
              //or the default Fruit constructor calls it as well?
  }
```

Comment: When you added diagnostic print statements to your constructors, you discovered what?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Oh....I didnt think of doing it that way. It turns out it does get called.

Comment: That design looks flawed as can be, I think you seriously are mistaking inheritance and subclassing.

Comment: Regarding `Private` and `Public` note that c++ is case sensitive.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was confused whether main object needs to call the constructor for some other types of objects inside...it turns out it calls the default constructor of others objects. And thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Lzy _" I was confused whether main object needs to call the constructor for some other types of objects inside."_ No, that's done implicitly. But the whole construct seems to be rather flawed. Shouldn't an `Apple` be a `Fruit`, instead of `Fruit` _contain_ an `Apple`??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ah I see what you mean. I guess my example is just bad..I didnt think this could mix up with inheritance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the default constructor gets called. If the apple constructor for example took a int as first param you would have to do set it through the initializer list:

```
class Apple
{
public:
    int kg;
    Apple(int _kg) : 
        kg(_kg)
    {}
};

class Fruit
{
private:
    int count;
    Apple one;

public:
    Fruit() : one(5) //right here or you'll get an error
    {
       this->count = 5;
       //this->one(5) doesn't work.
    }
};
```